# How can I move databse from an installation to a new one

Tags: database, database-migration, mamp

Good evening

I was using MAMP5.2 and I migrate to a newer version.
From my MacBook, I renamed /Application/MAMP to MAMP5-2
I installed a new version to /Application/MAMP and I move the content of htdocs to the new location.

I has a couple of database and now I need of of them to be moved to the new location.

I copied
/Applications/MAMAP5-2/db/mysql57/typ folder to
/Applications/MAMAP/db/mysql57/typ

On my PHPMyADMIN I could see the database but it generate errors
I supposed it was a bad idea to recover a database.

Is there another way to use my database with a new installation and how?

Many thank

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin you can use the export options on the old server and import them when you install the new server that you installed clean I hope this helps you